# Encode email in hex using Middleman?

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm building a small static website using Ruby and Middleman. With Rails I've been able to safely encode email links with the mail_to helper and the encode: 'hex' option;

`mail_to 'email@email.com', 'My Name', encode: 'hex'`

But when I try this in Middleman using the same code I wind up with this in my HTML;

```
<a encode="hex" href="mailto:email@email.com">My Name</a>
```

Any suggestions? I tried adding actionpack to my gemfile, but that didn't help.

Comment: Side note: That kind of “encoding” email addresses it pretty useless these days when it comes to spam bots “harvesting” addresses by simply scraping pages – it’s pretty simple to “decode” again, and if I was to write such a bot nowadays I would base it on some class/implementation that can parse HTML already instead of going through the trouble of implementing it myself … You will get spam anyways, so better invest in a good spam filter instead of in such useless measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both helpers from Middleman and Rails are called the same, they are actually not the same in code. Moreover, `encode` parameter has been removed from Rails 4 and you now have to require a [separate gem](https://github.com/reed/actionview-encoded_mail_to) to use it.

I think, your best option will be to look at [the code in that gem](https://github.com/reed/actionview-encoded_mail_to/blob/master/lib/action_view/encoded_mail_to/mail_to_with_encoding.rb#L99) and reimplement it as a separate helper for your Middleman project.